# How to use _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to use `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` to display memory leaks in my program.

But it does not display anything except for returning 0 in case of no memory leaks and 1 in case there is a leak.

The [link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=312742) here shows the output should be like:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
D:\VisualC++\CodeGuru\MemoryLeak\MemoryLeak.cpp(67) : {60} 
normal block at 0x00324818, 4 bytes long.
Data: <,   > 2C 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way of using this function.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have find the cause of the problem?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxszt639%28VS.80%29.aspx

In my case I was not setting the report modes. Try the sample program provided in the link and you will be able to see the output

Comment: Nowadays, I believe `/analyze` cmd argument does the job well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Download the sample from the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxszt639%28VS.80%29.aspx). You have to set the following parameters to direct output to console.

```
   // Send all reports to STDOUT
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
```

Answer (score 4):

After searching why it does not work in my code I found the following points:

- If there is no detected leak then this method prints nothing.
- Not all allocation methods are affected. For example `CoTaskMemAlloc` are not affected.
- The warning must be enabled with `_CrtSetReportMode` and `_CrtSetReportFile`.