# Why is _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks reporting a memory leak here?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2012

I want to check for memory leak in DEBUG mode. I use Windows and, to do this work, the function [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now, why this code finds a memory leak?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if(_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() == TRUE)
        std::cerr << "MEMORY LEAK!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT:

I add this code to direct output to console:

```
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: You should read the documentation on this. You are not using the api correctly yet. You don't have to put it in an if statement. It will print out its own message that says 'memory leak'.

Comment: So what is the question? Your MSDN link describes the function.

Comment: @CJohnson, what's wrong with his use of the function? From the doc:  "_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks returns TRUE if a memory leak is found". If it should not have been used in an `if`, is would have returned `void`.

Comment: @CJohnson: Though I must say that the OP is right about being confused, since the Documentations says: _"CrtDumpMemoryLeaks returns TRUE if a memory leak is found"_. Which is apparently what's happening too.

Comment: Its only showing all the stuff currently allocated on the heap, so it's probable that they aren't genuine leaks..  Perhaps there are some statically initialised heap objects allocated by the RTL.  Its better to use _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF) to dump any allocated blocks that haven't been freed at program exit.

Comment: Look at this question to get the actual dumped output. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153776/how-to-use-crtdumpmemoryleaks

Comment: Additionally, take a look at this to get a stack trace for the pioint where leaked objects were allocated:
http://vld.codeplex.com/
Makes your program run slow as hell but can be useful.  Alternatively, use AQTime.

Comment: @RomanR - His question is "why does the code shown report a memory leak?". Nothing there should cause a leak....

Comment: I tested your minimal program (adding the necessary headers and using namespace std) on Visual Studio 2010 (all patches installed) and of course it does not report a memory leak. Are you sure that exactly this program shows the leaks on your system? Or did you strip global variables that cause a memory leak?

Comment: The code as simple as this does not leak anything, and leak is not found. There might be however static objects defined elsewhere in code (e.g. with memory allocation in constructors), which are reported as leak.

Comment: @WernerHenze yes, I'm sure, but I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Comment: @Nick - see my answer below - are you sure you are running in DEBUG mode?

Comment: Here is a link that might be relevant as to how to use the function:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/2335/

Comment: @Nick: VS S2010 SP1 is free from this problem. If you feel like it is a bug with VS 2012 RC, I suggest you report it via http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Nick: I just installed VS 2012 RC (Version 11.0.50522.1) on Windows 7, created a new console app project, pasted your code in the main.cpp, deleted all other files (stdafx.h/cpp, targetver.h, *sdkver*.h?), switched off precompiled headers... and... it works without detecting memory leaks. If you want to, just mail me a minimum project and I will try to reproduce it here with your files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `<crtdbg.h>` ?

Are you sure you are running in debug mode?

In non-debug mode - the calls to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` are removed by the pre-processor leaving just `if(TRUE)`

EDIT:
Also to detect memory leaks you need to add the below lines to use the debug versions of malloc and free - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Can you try adding these?

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

Comment: Can you add a 
    `#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "DEBUG MODE!" << endl;
    #endif` to the code and see if it prints? Also I edited my answer - please add those lines to your code and see the output.

Comment: @Nick Ok, see the edits. And the includes must be in the order specified - or it will not work as the MSDN page says.

Comment: I read your edit, but it does not change anything. The result is always the same: a memory leak is detected (8 bytes), and if I add for example `int* i = new int;` and I don't delete `i` the `CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` function show the 4 bytes of the new memory leak too. So your answer is not a right answer!

Comment: if you found solution to this, could you post it here?